# list of dataframes spread across worksheets in single spreadsheet pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet with pandas that groups data by a code and puts each grouping in a separate tab in an excel spreadsheet.

So far I've created a list of dataframes but I cannot get each dataframe to be in it's own tab on the spreadsheet.

```
fss_infile = pd.ExcelFile('Report.xlsx')
lvl_1 = fss_infile.parse(sheet_name ='Lvl 1')
list_dfs = [lvl_1.loc[lvl_1['pc_code_last_4']==val, :] for val in lvl_1['pc_code_last_4'].unique()]

for i in list_dfs:
    i.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

How do I get each dataframe to be on a seperate tab with the name of pc_code_last_4 value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `pd.GroupBy` we create a blank excel object using `pd.ExcelWriter` and then loop over your data frame writing the relevant groups to your worksheet.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('myfile.xlsx')
for group, data in df.groupby('pc_code_last_4'):
    data.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=f"{group}")
    print(f"{group} saved to spreadsheet")
writer.save()
```

Comment: I got a type error to_excel()  got and unexpected argument 'sheet'

Comment: @tomoc4 apologies try `sheet_name` didnt test the code

Comment: Thanks dude. Your a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `ExcelWriter`. This should do:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for val in lvl_1['pc_code_last_4'].unique():
    df = lvl_1.loc[lvl_1['pc_code_last_4']==val, :]
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=val)
writer.save()
```

Comment: this solution does run properly. I get no error and no output sheet is made. Not sure why.